# Why is mega.nz not working with chrome or firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, memory, crash, mega

I have a 14.43 GB file in my cloud that i am trying to download off mega.nz. Which consists mostly of some recent manual backups of the desktop files in my mums old laptop, which now has been wiped clean.

I first started downloading my file using **google chrome** with the mega.nz extension, it would get up to 75% and crash. Oblivious to this crash, i tried again 3 more times and it would end with the same result (cant remember the details of the crash message but it wasn't much help).

After doing a little bit of research i found that it was a "bug" in the javascript engine of google chrome, where it would crash when the memory gets clunked up without releasing those blocks. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2534. After trying once again with releasing chromes cookies and deleting my temp memory, i ended up having the same results.

This was getting really annoying and just time consuming since my mum was left without a computer for her work and also that the download would start back from 0% each and every time it crashed (5-6hrs on my slow internet connection).

I used **mozilla firefox** because it was recommended and it finally reached 100% on the file transfer queue, after that i waited all night for the mozilla firefox to add it to its own download queue but it never happened. after doing a little bit more research, i found that some other users that were trying to download large files from their own mega cloud were having the same issue on firefox.

Any help on this subject would be greatly appreciated.

edit: I was using their official extensions in both browsers.

Comment: I don't know whats wrong with the chrome or firefox. if want to download you can use internatdownloadmanager on windows. try if it works

Comment: sorry what? i dont think that application is going to work because the download first happens natively. I think theres a decrypt process or a decompression, or something that happens internally before it lets the browser download. correct me if im wrong please.

Comment: Have you tried using their downloadable "sync client"? P.S.  Qs about online services are [off topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: sync client only works when you download from links or something. it doesn't help when you download it natively from your own cloud. at least thats been my experience with it. oh really? well i guess its open for closure. I found a temporary and a time consuming alternative to this, instead of downloading the full sized 13.43 gb file, i created partitions of the large file (1gb each) and downloaded that instead.

Comment: I always use jdownloader2 and never had issues with mega

Comment: A lot of software still misbehaves when given files larger than either 2GB or 4GB to handle... artefact of 32 bit signed or unsigned integers used to hold file sizes.

Comment: Is your PC going to sleep midway through the download?

Comment: Works fine with Opera.

Comment: I have the same problem, I have managed to ignore the problem downloading the mega files with Jdownloader, it's not a fix of the main issue, but at least you woulld be able to download the file

Answer (score 1):

Temporary and a time consuming solution to this, created partitions of the files in my main folder that i was trying to download inside the mega application. partitions of roughly about 1gb each made the process go a lot smoother.

other users have suggested using JDownloader, not a big fan of it myself but feel free to try it with mega.